# Insert a 4-digit as Time in MySql

Tags: mysql

My data contains hour & minute of time and I want to load this data into MySql database.
Sample Data: 305 -- This means Hours=03 & Minutes=05

But when I upload the data into MySql column of type TIME, it is stored as 00:03:05 (HH:MM:SS).

Whereas, I want it to be stored as 03:05:00.

I can make changes to my data using Python & then load into MySql. However, I was wondering if there is a way to do it using MySql itself.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I suggest _not_ going this route, and instead using MySQL time type as it is.  Actually, you probably should be storing `datetime`, that is, date and time, together.

Answer (score 2):

It is not up to MySQL to guess what you mean by "305". It's up to you to convert/format yor data to "03:05:00", then MySQL will undertand it properly.

```
insert into try (elasp) values ("03:05:00")
```

See MySQL documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html

Answer (score 2):

While converting to TIME datatype the numeric value is assumed to have `HHMMSS` format.

[MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  The TIME Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html):

> Be careful about assigning abbreviated values to a TIME column. MySQL interprets abbreviated TIME values with colons as time of the day. That is, '11:12' means '11:12:00', not '00:11:12'. **MySQL interprets abbreviated values without colons using the assumption that the two rightmost digits represent seconds** (that is, as elapsed time rather than as time of day). For example, you might think of '1112' and 1112 as meaning '11:12:00' (12 minutes after 11 o'clock), but MySQL interprets them as '00:11:12' (11 minutes, 12 seconds). Similarly, '12' and 12 are interpreted as '00:00:12'.

If you want to use `HHMM` format during convertion then simply multiply the value by 100.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (int_source INT, time_destination TIME);
> INSERT INTO test (int_source) VALUES ('305');
> SELECT * FROM test;
> UPDATE test SET time_destination = int_source * 100;
> SELECT * FROM test;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> int_source | time_destination
> ---------: | :---------------
>        305 | null            
>
> ✓
>
> int_source | time_destination
> ---------: | :---------------
>        305 | 03:05:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ac805814ca8f4daccb0ed6f3f1cab5f5)*

Or, if the value to be converted to TIME datatype has some string type you may concatenate `'00'` to it:

```
SET time_destination = CONCAT(int_source, '00')
```